# Why does res.json() return fine on localhost but not on a live website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx, fetch-api

I've been trying to send JSON data from server to client via endpoints using `fetch()`, but in the developer console it gives a 404 Missing File error. When I create folders named after the endpoints, it changes to a 403 Forbidden, even though it has the same permissions as any other folder. How do I get the endpoints set up properly? I can provide any more requested details

Comment: folders?  How are you serving these files?  Express, by default, does not serve ANY files.  So you will need to have a specific route to serve a file or use middleware with `express.static()` pointed at a specific directory intended to serve files to the public or have nginx configured to serve your static files.

Comment: I had the idea that the endpoints needed to be real folders if I had a 404.

this is the function used for one endpoint:

`app.get("/latest", (req, res) => {
 let file = fs.readFileSync("messages.json");
 jsonFile = JSON.parse(file);
 res.json(jsonFile.messages[jsonFile.messages.length-1].text);
});` and it returns 404

Comment: Express endpoints have absolutely nothing to do with your file system.  Endpoints are defined purely in software.  So, a 404 either means that no route you've defined in Express matches the incoming request or one of your matching routes is explicitly returning a 404 status.  If you have specific code you want help with, please add that code to your actual question and include enough overall context for us to be able to follow the flow of the incoming requeset.  As it stands now, there's not enough information here to be able to help you.